How to revert an automatic system update from Android 12 back to Android 11
Despite having disallowed every possible automatic update option available, today my phone updated automatically from Android 11 to Android 12 after a short WiFi connection.
How can I get Android 11 back?
I don't care about loosing any data on the phone?

Android phone with locked bootloader usually have a downgrade protection, so you can't. Anyway what is the problem with Android 12?

Very likely, you need to download a stock firmware with Android 11, and then flash it into the phone. Not all phones loves it.

@Robert Adb scripts not working anymore. But actually it's me: I didn't ask for it
